# Cannot open While accessing file audio file for accessing file

Tags: swift, audio, containers, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently working on an speech to text related app.

I am done with recording in `childBottomSheet` on dismiss of child bottom sheet I sent back the file URL to `parentVC` when I tried to access that URL for transcribing from audio to text nothing found there.

Here is the code

The line below is for obtaining the file path, and it returns the container's path:

```
FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("audioNote",      isDirectory: false)
```

The path below is where the audio is located:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D2759ADB-6085-4663-9BB1-FF0A448CB901/tmp/audioNote
```

but it gives an error "Cannot Open" when trying to transcribe.